# Scala sbt multi/module projects: how to deal with relative paths?

Tags: scala, sbt

This could be a silly question, but I haven't found a solution to this problem. I have a multi-module project with sub-projects (sub1, sub2). Here's a figure:

```
main
  +-- sub1
        +-- src/main/resources/cfg.properties
  +-- sub2
```

I have a cfg file in sub1 and I load it from a class defined in `sub1` path using `File("./src/main/resources/cfg.properties")` and it works fine. If I move to  `sub2` path and I run the projects, I get a 'file not found' when accessing the class defined in sub1 that loads the file because the path is relative.

What is the best approach to solve this issue? I'd say that absolute paths could be a solution, but they are not portable to other positions in the file system nor other machines.

I suppose there are best practices to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

Sub1 is the name of a sub-project

```
  val commonResource      = (resourceDirectory in sub1 in Compile).value
  fileCopy(baseDir = commonResource, source = "application-ref.conf", target = "application.conf", logMessage = "Akka AppConf")


 def fileCopy(baseDir: File, source: String, target: String, logMessage: String)(implicit log: Logger) = {
val sourceFile = baseDir / source
val targetFile = baseDir / target
IO.copyFile(sourceFile, targetFile)
log.info(s"Copied: $logMessage: [$sourceFile -> $targetFile]")
```

}